# show text field on select other from drop down :ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How I should do this using javascript? I looked other places but every example uses Jquery.

Only on select other textbox should visible.

Comment: Which version of ROR?  If 3.0.x then you should just upgrade to 3.1 and use jQuery, since it becomes the default JS engine. (see [here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/5/22/rails-3-1-release-candidate))

Comment: I am using older version 2.3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are on an older version of rails which has prototype as the js library.

in the onchange event of the select list add the javascript function to show the div containing the text box (let's say you show the text box for value 5 of the select list):

```
<select id="select_item" name="select_item" onchange="display_date_range(this);">
... where 5 is the value of the option that needs to show text box
</select>

  function display_date_range(list) {
    if(list.options[list.selectedIndex].value == 5) {
      $("text_div").show();
    }
    else {
      $("text_div").hide();
    }
  }

<div id="text_div"><input type="text" value="Hooraaahhh..." /></div>
```